# Necessary permissions to edit user details in AD

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

I need to delegate permissions to edit user information (phone numbers, address, etc) in AD.  Its a 2003 domain.  Ive already delegated: 'Read all user information' and 'Read, Write, Read and write general information,  Read and write phone and mail options, read and write public information, read and write personal information.

So far none of these have helped the specific user edit details.  Its been logged off and back on already too.

What am i missing?

Comment: Try using the ACL editor directly, instead of the delegation wizard.  Check for `Deny` ACEs against any groups that user might be in?

Comment: i found no Deny entries at all

Comment: it looks like this is now not working only for specific users, still not sure why but its good for the majority of the objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, that sounds like AdminSDHolder protection.  Check if inheritance is disabled for the users' ACLs, and/or check the value of the adminCount property on the objects.  This occurs for users that are in (or sometimes, *were once in*) one of the protected administrative groups.  See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817433).

Comment: i cant check right now but knowing the list of people that couldnt be edited, im almost 100% certain you are correct.